# Arraylist IndexOutOfBoundsException after removing element

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist

I know it is dumb question but I already spent 1,5 hour by looking in the code and did not find anything:

```
holder.removeQuestion
                    .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            // Button b = (Button) v;
                            // Question question = (Question) b.getTag();
                            Log.i("before removing", questionList.get(0)
                                    .getQuestion());
                            questionList.remove(0);
                            dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            Log.i("after removing", questionList.get(0)
                                    .getQuestion());
                        }
                    });
```

The line: `questionList.remove(0)` is the problem, but why? The list is full of elements and I just want to remove the first one, how can it be outofbound? I was thinking that maybe it happens later in code where I use the list again and maybe I am saying somewhere that I expect bigger arraylist than I actually give.

```
07-07 13:24:08.005: I/before removing(16695): Ako?
07-07 13:24:08.005: I/after removing(16695): Sa?
07-07 13:24:08.009: V/ConvertView(16695): 0
07-07 13:24:08.009: V/ConvertView(16695): 1
07-07 13:24:08.013: V/ConvertView(16695): 2
07-07 13:24:08.017: D/AndroidRuntime(16695): Shutting down VM
07-07 13:24:08.017: W/dalvikvm(16695): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught     
exception (group=0xa62b1288)
07-07 13:24:08.021: E/AndroidRuntime(16695): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-07 13:24:08.021: E/AndroidRuntime(16695): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException:     
Invalid index 2, size is 2
07-07 13:24:08.021: E/AndroidRuntime(16695):    at     
java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
07-07 13:24:08.021: E/AndroidRuntime(16695):    at 
java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
07-07 13:24:08.021: E/AndroidRuntime(16695):    at 
com.example.discue.Discussion$MyCustomAdapter.getView
```

If you need also further code just comment I will add. I did not want to overspam you.

EDIT(onView method):

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        Log.v("ConvertView", String.valueOf(position));

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) 
getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.question_list, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.question = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.question);
            holder.checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
            holder.likes = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.numberOfLikes);
            // create button for deleting question (for speaker)
            holder.removeQuestion = (Button) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.deleteQuestionBtn);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
            // set onclick listener on remove question button
            holder.removeQuestion
                    .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            // Button b = (Button) v;
                            // Question question = (Question) b.getTag();
                            Log.i("before removing", questionList.get(0)
                                    .getQuestion());
                            questionList.remove(0);
                            dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            Log.i("after removing", questionList.get(0)
                                    .getQuestion());
                        }
                    });
            // set onclick listener on like check box for question
            holder.checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
                    Question question = (Question) cb.getTag();
                    if (cb.isChecked()) {
                        // update number of likes under like button
                        question.setLikes(question.getLikes() + 1);

                    } else {
                        question.setLikes(question.getLikes() - 1);
                    }

                    // resort the arraylist of questions
                    Collections.sort(questionList,
                            new Comparator<Question>() {
                                public int compare(Question q1, Question q2) {
                                    return (q2.getLikes() - q1.getLikes());
                                }
                            });
                    // execute the update
                    dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    question.setSelected(cb.isChecked());
                }
            });
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        Question question = questionList.get(position);
        // show/hide question remove button (for the first question)
        if (question.isRemoveButtonVisible()) {
            holder.removeQuestion.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            holder.removeQuestion.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        // show/ hide question likes
        if (question.isLikeButtonVisible()) {
            holder.checkBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            holder.checkBox.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        // set checked/unchecked and disabled/not disabled like check boxes
        // (all except for the first question)
        if (question.isLikeDisabled()) {
            holder.checkBox.setChecked(true);
            holder.checkBox.setEnabled(false);
        } else {
            holder.checkBox.setChecked(question.isSelected());
            holder.checkBox.setEnabled(true);

        }
        holder.question.setText(question.getQuestion());
        holder.likes.setText(question.getLikes() + "");
        holder.checkBox.setTag(question);
        holder.removeQuestion.setTag(question);
        dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        return convertView;

    }
```

Comment: your error is on MyCustomAdapter.getView, not questionList.remove. Please post this method implementation.

Comment: `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException:     
Invalid index 2, size is 2`  You accessing 2 somewhere (by variable or hardcoded).  The method you posted isn't the code where the error is happening.  Can you post the relevant code?

Comment: Pretty clear error message: `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 2, size is 2`.

Comment: Since you get all outputs that means it passed from all the code. Somewhere else is the error. Double click the logcat lines and one of them will take you to the error

Comment: Question is edited, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The position given to you in getView should take into account the size of the data.

My guess is, when you create the adapter, you're giving it a certain list (the question list), but at some point later on, you're creating a new instance of the list locally and modifying it without updating the adapter.

Make sure any changes you make to the list are on the same list instance and no new list instance are created.

Comment: Ou you are totally right. I create new instance and I pass arraylist through constructor. Thanks I am gonna fix it.

Comment: any chance you set this as the correct answer then? :)

Answer (score 2):

The error occurs here:

```
Question question = questionList.get(position);
```

The `position` is `2` and that is out of the bound.  You may want to do a check before or prevent the method from getting a `position` value that is equal to or larger than the size of `questionList`.  It seems your list in the U.I. has more items than the `questionList` has Questions

Comment: I think you are right, I got another error but my problem is gone, I am going to mark as answer as soon as you tell me why the position is 2? What is the position? I mean I know it is a parameter but dont you know how do I get that, from where is it?

Comment: @OndrejTokar On your application, is the list on the front end (U.I.) made up of more than 2 items?  Are you manipulating this list of questions anywhere else?

Comment: Yes by adding elements into list through edit text if you meant that.